# How to redirect folders to index.php using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, directory

Folder structure:

```
/index/
/upload/
/something/
```

These folders don't have .htaccess in them(and shouldn't).

When accessing **http://site.com/something** it redirects to **http://site.com/something/url=something**, which is not desired.

```
RewriteEngine on

# RewriteBase /base/ #

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Adding another rewrite condition for appending '/' at the end of folders makes an additional(and unnecessary) request, also not nice.

How do I write the rule so that even folders are sent directly to the front controller without any unwanted redirects?

Comment: In the root .htaccess

Comment: Why is there a `RewriteBase /base/` if it's in the root?

Comment: The full path is something like this **www.site.com/base/something**, base is one of the apps running inside the site.

Comment: got the same question... all the .htaccess redirects ignore existing files and folders. But i want EVERYTHING to be redirected...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an additional condition to exclude existing directories:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: If I use this, when I go to **www.site.com/something** it will redirect me to **www.site.com/something/?url=something**. I want the rewrite engine to treat existing folders like a virtual path.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [NC,L,R=301]
```

But this makes an additional redirect(first to something/ and the another to index.php?url...) ... not optimal.

A good solution would be only one redirect, no matter what.